# Are there any other SIP implementations for iPhone besides Siphon?

Tags: iphone, sip, voip

I'm trying to build a SIP app for iPhone 4 (iOS 4.2).
Tried to use [siphon](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/), but no success (`IOKit.framework` is missing from the sdk, `libg729a.a` is also missing).

Is there any other way to implement SIP for iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Check out **[pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/)**, and their [iPhone Getting Started Guide](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone).  Siphon uses it too, but hasn't been updated for quite a while (which explains the build issues with the new SDKs.)

Comment: Thanks sdloan, I have downloaded it and compiled it (iPhone 4, iOS 4.2) , but it seems to have audio problems since I can't hear a thing when state is CALLING.

Comment: @CarlsoRicardo:  Worked with one (forget the name) in some contract work it was $100k. :/

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is a pure SIP stack, then we are licensing a commercial one for customers: http://www.radvision.com/Products/Developer/VoIP-Developer-Tools/SIP-Developer-Suite/

Comment: Hi. How can I get the kit? who should I contact?

Comment: Just leave your information on my blog's contact page - I'll pass it to the relevant person: http://blog.radvision.com/voipsurvivor/contact/